# Ubuntu 14.04 not installing, popup error ??? at "where are you?"

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, ubiquity, dmraid

I'm having an issue trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.

When booting up the CD, I select "Install Ubuntu" which is fine, however the problem occurs each time I arrive at the "where are you?" screen when choosing your geographic location.
I select my location and I always get a pop-up with the following error message: ??? ???

[image]

Literally, that is all it shows! I've tried installing using a USB stick too and the same thing occurs at the same bit. It also happens on 13.10 as well.

Eachtime i select OK on the error message, I am taking back to the start of the installation again.

Any ideas?

I am using a HP Microserver N40L.

- [syslog](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7308234/Ubuntu/2/syslog.txt)
- [/var/log/partman](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7308234/Ubuntu/2/partman.txt)
- [/var/log/installer/debug](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7308234/Ubuntu/2/debug.txt)

**/var/log/installer/debug**

```
Exception caught in process_line:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/filteredcommand.py", line 145, in process_line
    return self.dbfilter.process_line()
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/debconffilter.py", line 430, in process_line
    data = self.db.command(command, *params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debconf.py", line 66, in command
    self.write.write("%s %s\n" % (command, ' '.join(map(str, params))))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

**/var/log/syslog**

*/dev/mapper/pdc_eajbihdagf* errors

```
Jul 29 10:58:30 ubuntu activate-dmraid: Enabling dmraid support.
Jul 29 10:58:30 ubuntu dmraid-activate: ERROR: Cannot retrieve RAID set information for pdc_eajbihdagf
Jul 29 10:58:30 ubuntu dmraid-activate: ERROR: Cannot retrieve RAID set information for pdc_eajbihdagf
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   87.667498] xor: measuring software checksum speed
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   87.706052]    prefetch64-sse:  6157.000 MB/sec
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   87.746058]    generic_sse:  5808.000 MB/sec
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   87.746062] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (6157.000 MB/sec)
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   87.834089] raid6: sse2x1    2173 MB/s
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   87.902132] raid6: sse2x2    3197 MB/s
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   87.970134] raid6: sse2x4    4002 MB/s
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   87.970138] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 (4002 MB/s)
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   87.970141] raid6: using intx1 recovery algorithm
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   88.023211] bio: create slab <bio-3> at 3
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   88.023698] Btrfs loaded
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   88.093940] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu kernel: [   88.171643] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu partman:   No matching physical volumes found
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu partman:   Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu partman:   No volume groups found
Jul 29 10:58:31 ubuntu partman-lvm:   No volume groups found
Jul 29 10:58:34 ubuntu ubiquity: tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/pdc_eajbihdagf
Jul 29 10:58:34 ubuntu ubiquity: Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
Jul 29 10:58:34 ubuntu partman: Error running 'tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/pdc_eajbihdagf'
```

*ubiquity errors*

```
Jul 29 12:04:19 ubuntu ubiquity[10648]: switched to page timezone
Jul 29 12:04:20 ubuntu ubiquity[10648]: Geoname lookup for "New York" failed: 2 Cannot resolve hostname (geoname-lookup.ubuntu.com)
Jul 29 12:04:25 ubuntu ubiquity[10648]: Geoname lookup for "London" failed: 2 Cannot resolve hostname (geoname-lookup.ubuntu.com)
```

*other errors*

```
Jul 29 14:59:22 ubuntu kernel: [  616.983294] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache entry [26f79ee9]
Jul 29 14:59:22 ubuntu kernel: [  616.983297] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 26f79ee9, size cf29
Jul 29 14:59:22 ubuntu kernel: [  616.983302] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache entry [26f79ee9]
Jul 29 14:59:22 ubuntu kernel: [  616.983305] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 26f79ee9, size cf29
Jul 29 14:59:22 ubuntu kernel: [  616.983309] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache entry [26f79ee9]
Jul 29 14:59:22 ubuntu kernel: [  616.983311] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 26f79ee9, size cf29

Jul 29 14:59:38 ubuntu kernel: [  633.244836] FAT-fs (sdc1): Directory bread(block 15262) failed
Jul 29 14:59:38 ubuntu kernel: [  633.244846] FAT-fs (sdc1): Directory bread(block 15263) failed
Jul 29 14:59:38 ubuntu kernel: [  633.244850] FAT-fs (sdc1): Directory bread(block 15264) failed
```

Comment: Have you checked the MD5sum of your downloaded image with the one thats provided on the Ubuntu download server? Maybe there occured a n error upon downloading. You could also check your image on boot: Press F12 when Ubuntu is starting from DVD/USB Stick and seleck "Check disk for errors".

Comment: Hi Flatron, Yeah i checked the MD5sum on the image and it verified OK, so no issues there. Will try and do the "check disks for errors".

Comment: Okay, hopefully thats the problem. Btw. what program did you use to burn your iso onto the DVD / Stick?

Comment: Just completed a disk check and no errors were returned.

I just used the default windows 7 disk image burner and for the USB i used the "Universal USB Installer" program.

Still seem to be getting the same error :(.

Comment: Have you tried a plain English installation? Maybe it's an internationalisation bug. Which other settings did you choose before the question marks appear?

Comment: Which language did you select?

Comment: I have tried leaving it as default and quickly selecting next, however when i get to the next page to choose keyboard localisation settings, the same error appears and back to the start.

That's as far as i've ever gotten with the installation.

Comment: I select UK as my "where are you" normally. But have left it as default and still no go.

Comment: Are there any errors in `/var/log/installer/debug` or `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Try installing Ubuntu from the live session and launch the installer from a terminal with "sudo ubiquity".

Comment: Hey guys,

Tried installing from the live session and by using the "sudo ubiquity" command, however the same error occured in the same place.

Here are the log files, i can't make much sense from them.
[link]https://db.tt/2fUJSg3v

[link]https://db.tt/3NlAMg1I

Comment: The first logfile does not look too rpomising. I think I'd get me a new ISO on a fresh stick / CD regardless of the MD5...

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go and report my findings!

Comment: "Cannot resolve hostname (geoname-lookup.ubuntu.com)" - is your internet connection working in the Ubuntu desktop? Can you try an install with "internet updates" off?

Comment: The internet connection works only when the proxy is setup. However, i have disconnected all networking and unchecked any automatic updates.
Doesn't appear to have had any effect.

Comment: Just tried a fresh image along with a new usb and cd, error still seems to be occuring. Slowly giving up! not easy to tackle this one.

Comment: Do you have some kind of RAID setup - there are errors about being unable to mount */dev/mapper/pdc_eajbihdagf*? Can you run `ubiquity --debug` and then post the same log files as before, and `/var/log/partman`? It is possible you have hit a rare bug, or that there is some problem with your particular PC.

Comment: I suspect the error "???  ???" is reported by partman when something throws an error (it is meant to print the actual error text between the ??? characters but this does not seem to be happening).

Comment: I will provide that partman log shortly.

I do indeed have RAID1 setup on the server, but i know Ubunutu has installed and worked fine before on the server because a few months back it had v12.X on it before I wiped it.

Comment: Can you also provide `/var/log/installer/debug` and `/var/log/syslog` after you have run ubiquity with debugging. Are you trying to install to the RAID1 drives? What might be happening here is that partman is failing to partition your RAID drives and throwing a useless error. Hopefully the partman log will have more information.

Comment: Can you check this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/197561/installing-ubuntu-with-fake-raid-1 - the reported errors closely match yours.

Comment: Log files attached.
[Link]https://db.tt/z2vrIcmY
[Link]https://db.tt/laV6NsDA
[Link]https://db.tt/iHV7oUOP
Will try the above solution as well and let you know.

Comment: Having had a look at the solution above, I don't get the option to choose or modify a partition or hard drive. 

All i get is, "Erase Disk and install Ubuntu" then that takes me straight to the "Where are you?" part of the setup.

Comment: partman gets an exception accessing your disk - there are numerous errors in the kernel log _"FAT-fs (sdc1): Directory bread(block 15262) failed"_ and _"SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block"_. These are errors communicating with the hard drive and CDROM. It could be caused by BIOS settings (IDE settings=Compatibility mode?) but is usually caused by hardware failure or bad media. See [SquashfsErrors](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SquashfsErrors) and [bug #172937 -
 SQUASHFS error while booting from live cd](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/172937)

Comment: I would try installing 12.04 again using exactly the same setup including same install media. If there is no error, then you have probably found a bug in 14.04 and should report it on Launchpad. If 12.04 install fails then check your hardware, check disks with smartmontools, investigate BIOS settings for SATA/PATA controller, try turning off the motherboard RAID etc.

Comment: btw you do not get the option to choose a disk because partman detects that you only have one drive - the RAID device - and selects it automatically. And watch out with "erase disk" - it really will erase the whole disk.

Comment: Hey Bain,

Downloaded and have now successfully installed 12.04 without any issues. This is still using RAID1 setup.

The main reason I wanted to wipe the server and install 14.04 was because I was unable to update to that version through the Software Update tool because of the proxy settings my server is behind and for some reason it won't download or install it.

I think I'll just have to stick with 12.04 unless you have any ideas??

Thanks for your help so far! you've been a great help.

Comment: Odd. Report it on Launchpad as a bug in 14.04. It might be something to do with your RAID setup, like http://askubuntu.com/questions/455511/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-7-on-fakeraid-installation-error-question-m?rq=1 or it could be a bug in the kernel.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I tried different downloads; USB, live boot DVD.  The error remained.  I then removed my RAID drive and converted them to none RAID and it installed perfectly.