# Error when trying to install Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: system-installation

I burnt the ISO (64bit version) to a disk and attempted to install it on my PC (with Win7 already installed on it).  When I selected the option to  "erase disk and install ubuntu", it gives me an error that I'm not able to click out of.  It goes to the next section ("Where are you"?) but I'm not able to do anything cause of the error.

The error is: "??? ???" as the title.  And the info box "??? ???".  Really descriptive huh?

I tried burning another disk (thinking it was screwy) and I got the same thing.  I really don't want Windows on this PC, wanting it to just be a linux box.

Any ideas on what to do?

Thank you!

Some other notes I should add.. I have more than enough space on my HDD, and I'm connected hard wired for ethernet.

Comment: how did you download the ISO, torrent or direct download? The Download could have gone bad I would recommend the torrent option.

Comment: Building on @Klyn's comment... Check the md5 of the iso that you downloaded (see here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) You can download a tool from microsoft to do so on windows here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533

Comment: This error seems to have been encountered before - e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/504055/ubuntu-14-04-not-installing-popup-error-at-where-are-you, http://wyldeplayground.net/question-mark-error-when-installing-from-cdusb/, https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2012-May/087059.html, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1767203 ...